# The problem that cassandra4.x delete read repair brings

Tags: cql

Cassandra4.x canceled the read repair strategy, so I can only repair it manually through nodetool? Also, let's say my reads are buggy, but don't even if manually fixed via nodetool, will the bugs keep growing without background read fixes?

My purpose is to test some performance of the database